# hg remove -I PATTERN, how it works?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Ho to remove all *.bak or *.orig files in mercurial?

example:

```
C:\dev\web>hg stat
? Views\System\UnderConstruction.cshtml.bak
? Views\Topic\Index.cshtml.bak
? Views\Topic\MasterPage.cshtml.bak
? Web.config.bak

C:\dev\web>hg rem -I *.bak
abort: no files specified
```

Answer (score 5):

`hg remove` only removes files that have already been committed. AFAIK, there is no command in mercurial to remove untracked files.

To learn how file patterns work in mercurial, run `hg help patterns`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Untracked files ("?" sign) can be removed by OS, not Mercurial
2. You have to leave files as is, just add patterns to .hgignore and after it files, matching patterns, will not apper in `hg status` anymore
3. **Correct** remove command for *remove tracked bak and orig* files will be `hg remove -I **.bak -I **.orig`

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [`hg purge`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension) extension:

> Delete files not known to Mercurial. This is useful to test local and
>   uncommitted changes in an otherwise-clean source tree.
>
> This means that purge will delete:
>
> - Unknown files: files marked with "?" by "hg status"
> - Empty directories: in fact Mercurial ignores directories unless they   contain files under source control management
>
> But it will leave untouched:
>
> - Modified and unmodified tracked files
> - Ignored files (unless --all is specified)
> - New files added to the repository (with "hg add")
>
> If directories are given on the command line, only files in these
>   directories are considered.
>
> Be careful with purge, as you could irreversibly delete some files you
>   forgot to add to the repository. If you only want to print the list of
>   files that this program would delete, use the --print option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following two commands:

```
D:\workspace>hg purge -I **/*.orig --all
```

and then:

```
D:\workspace>hg purge -I **/*.bak --all
```

Tracked files won't be deleted, but I'm guessing that's not an issue for you. Make sure that you enable the purge extension before running this, and you can do dry runs with the `--print` argument.